# Why can't I std::apply for a member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, apply, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to develop a wrapper to help people use `pthread` on calling any member function.

```
template <typename>
struct signature;

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct signature<R (C::*)(Args...)> {
    using return_type        = R;
    using pure_argument_type = std::tuple<C*, std::tuple<Args...>>; // obj, {args...}
    using argument_type =
        std::tuple<R (C::*)(Args...), pure_argument_type>; // obj.mem_fn, {obj, args...}
};
    
struct Job {
public:
    Job()  = default;
    ~Job() = default;

    void join() { pthread_join(btd, nullptr); }

    template <typename C, typename F, typename... Args>
    int run(F C::*f, C* c, Args&&... args) {
        typename signature<decltype(f)>::pure_argument_type pureParams =
            std::make_tuple(c, std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
        typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type params = std::make_tuple(f, pureParams);

        return pthread_create(
            &btd, nullptr,
            [](void* p) {
                auto param = static_cast<typename signature<decltype(f)>::argument_type*>(p);
                std::apply(std::get<0>(*param), std::get<1>(*param)); ////// ERROR!
                return (void*)nullptr;
            },
            &params);
    }

private:
    pthread_t btd;
};
```

However, when I try to do as below,

```
class Test {
public:
    void func(int& a, double& d) { a = 2; d = 2.0; }

    void dojob() {
        int a = 0;
        double d = 0.0;
        Job job;
        job.run(&Test::func, this, std::ref(a), std::ref(d));
        job.join();
        std::cout << "a:" << a << " d:" << d << std::endl;
    }
};

Test t;
t.dojob();
```

I get the error:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/map:61,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/tuple: In instantiation of 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::__apply_impl(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&, std::index_sequence<_Idx ...>) [with _Fn = void (Test::*&)(int&, double&); _Tuple = std::tuple<Test*, std::tuple<int&, double&> >&; long unsigned int ..._Idx = {0, 1}; std::index_sequence<_Idx ...> = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0, 1>]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/tuple:1854:31:   required from 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::apply(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&) [with _Fn = void (Test::*&)(int&, double&); _Tuple = std::tuple<Test*, std::tuple<int&, double&> >&]'
<source>:98:27:   required from 'int Job::run(F C::*, C*, Args&& ...) [with C = Test; F = void(int&, double&); Args = {std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::reference_wrapper<double>}]'
<source>:118:16:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/tuple:1843:27: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(void (Test::*&)(int&, double&), Test*&, std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<Test*, std::tuple<int&, double&> > >&)'
 1843 |       return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Fn>(__f),
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1844 |                            std::get<_Idx>(std::forward<_Tuple>(__t))...);
      |
```

You can get my code here: https://godbolt.org/z/sMjcxvP33

Comment: I'm curious, why do you use POSIX thread functions instead of `std::thread`? And why limit your `run` function to only member functions, why not do like the standard library and use a single template argument for the callable object/function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because my company developed its own `thread`, which is `pthread` style. I have to use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not very good at template programming. If one single `run` can accept common function and member function, that would be great... I can try.

Comment: Also, the error you have included in the question isn't complete. Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into your question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That gonna be too long... You could get it here: https://godbolt.org/z/sMjcxvP33

Comment: Why you pack all parameters in a tuple and expand them later? You can pass them direct, or I am wrong? And why you use the mysterious construct to pass an object and member pointer instead of any callable object type? All the stuff is curious and I believe fully unnecessary.

Comment: @Klaus I need to wrap the parameters into one object so that I can pass them together as the forth parameter of `pthread_create()`. Do we have any better method...

Comment: You can just define `pure_argument_type` as `std::tuple<C*, Args...>` then use `std::make_tuple(c, args...)` to construct it, which makes your code work and much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `std::get<1>(*param)` is `std::tuple<C*, std::tuple<Args...>>`.

Since the type of the second element of this `tuple` is also  a `tuple`, you need to use `std::apply` to expand it again, something like this

```
std::apply(
  [f = std::get<0>(*param)](auto* obj, auto&& args) {
    std::apply([&](auto&&... args) { 
      (obj->*f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); 
    }, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args));
  },
  std::get<1>(*param));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WhP3of5Eh)

Another alternative is to flatten the nested `tuple` to `std::tuple<C*, Args...>` and then pass it to `std::apply` along with `f`.

```
std::apply(
  std::get<0>(*param),
  std::tuple_cat(
    std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(std::get<1>(*param))),
                    std::get<1>(std::get<1>(*param))));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7dv4EoTff)

Answer (score 2):

`std::apply` needs a *single* tuple that contains all the arguments, not tuples nested within one another.

You have a race condition, if your lambda hasn't copied the arguments into the parameters of `std::apply` by the point when `run` returns you will be dereferencing a dangling pointer.

```
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
struct signature<R (C::*)(Args...)> {
    using return_type        = R;
    using pure_argument_type = std::tuple<C*, Args...>; // obj, args...
    struct argument_type {
        R (C::*fun)(Args...);
        pure_argument_type args;
    };
};
    
struct Job {
public:
    Job()  = default;
    ~Job() = default;

    void join() { pthread_join(btd, nullptr); }

    template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
    int run(R (C::*f)(Args...), C* c, Args&&... args) {
        using params_t = typename signature<R (C::*)(Args...)>::argument_type;

        auto * params = new params_t{f, std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(c), std::forward_as_tuple(args...))};

        return pthread_create(
            &btd, nullptr,
            [](void* p) {
                auto param = static_cast<params_t*>(p);
                std::apply(param->fun, param->args);
                delete param;
                return (void*)nullptr;
            },
            params);
    }

private:
    pthread_t btd;
};
```

Comment: Oh, nice one. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

This example show you how to use apply command right way in 2023.

```
template<typename ... TypyParametru>
decltype(auto) vypustky(TypyParametru...arg)
{
    // Create std::tuple z předaných hodnot
    std::tuple<TypyParametru...> hodnoty(arg...);

   // print all the values from std::tuple
    std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::apply([](const auto&... args)
    {
        ((std::cout << args << " "), ...);
    }, hodnoty);

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The important part is captured in this command:

```
std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::apply
```

The command is nested in experimental::fundamentals_v1.